# Javascript - any way to access child properties only if they exist?

Tags: javascript

I'm thinking it would be useful to have something like:

```
let data = { item : { subItem: { text: 'Nested thing' } } }

if(data.?item.?subItem.?text){
    //do something
}
```

Which would be shorthand for

```
if( data && data.item && data.item.subItem && data.item.subItem.text )
```

Can this be done? What would this be called?

Comment: *"Is this achievable with any available frameworks currently?'* makes this an off-topic question: *"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam."*

Comment: which consept string or array

Comment: @Bhargav what is a consept string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment the way you are doing it is the best one (performance speaking, code clarity and debuggability), usually objects doesn't get that nested deeper.

A (worse) option would be to simply access the member and use a try/catch construct to otherwise continue.

However for the future there is a feature called [optional chaining](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining) planned, which will directly offer the functionality you where talking about. As userqwert stated with `babel-plugin-transform-optional-chaining` (currently in alpha) one can use that feature now/in the short future.

Comment: Ah brilliant, I didnt know it was called optional chaining. I think this is what I am looking for - https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/7.0/packages/babel-plugin-transform-optional-chaining
Not quite ready yet though!

Answer (score 0):

Here's the function I use

```
getValue(element,path) {
    "use strict";
    if (!Array.isArray(path)) {
        throw new Error("The first parameter must be an array");
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < path.length; i++) {
        if (typeof element == "object" && typeof element[path[i]] != "undefined") {
            element = element[path[i]];
        } else {
            return undefined;
        }
    }
    return element;
}
```

For your example, should be called like so

```
getValue(data,['item','subItem','text']);
```

This has some draw back though... But does the job.

If you wanted you could use this and work out a way to make it work directly on the Object prototype.

Comment: This looks like a pretty nice idea, what are the drawbacks?

Comment: Well it appears to require lodash... Why not Array.isArray instead? Will it work if the last value in the property chain is zero or false or empty string? I think youd get undefined in those cases which seems incorrect

Comment: You are right. This is a very poor implementation that fitted our need. Actually it was returning false before I edit it for my answer. You can definitely improve it.

Comment: Here I fixed some parts. Should return undefined only when one of the property isn't found.